# using Powershell to place a wpf control element into a grid

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, label

I have a situation where i need to be able to programatically generate a control element and place it into a grid.

if i premake the control in the xaml it is pretty straight forward:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Name='NewGrid'>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="Row1" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="Row2"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="col1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="col2"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label 
        Name='Buttonlabel' 
        HorizontalAlignment='Left' 
        Content="ButtonLabel"
        VerticalAlignment='Top' 
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
```

This will place my Label into Row '0' and column '1'.  But if i have a function in Powershell that is generating the label, i have no way of placing the label in Grid.Row='0', Grid.Column='1'. since location properties do not naturally exist when i create the label like this:

```
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
$label.Name = 'ButtonLabel'
$label.Content = 'ButtonLabel'
$label.HorizontalAlignment ='Left'
$label.VerticalAlignment ='top'
$label.FontWeight ='Bold'
$label.Grid.Row = '0' (error property not found)
$label.Grid.Column = '1' (error property not found)
```

Any ideas on how to place an item in to a grid like this?

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION

Here is the complete (working) function where i am calling this in case anyone needs a sample:

```
Function CreateRow{

$grd = New-Object system.windows.controls.grid
$grd.Name = "InnerGrid"
$grd.ShowGridLines = 'True'
$row1 = new-object system.windows.controls.rowdefinition
$row1.height = "Auto"
$row2 = new-object system.windows.controls.rowdefinition
$row2.height = "Auto"
$col1 = new-object system.windows.controls.columndefinition
$col1.width = "Auto"
$col2 = new-object system.windows.controls.columndefinition
$col2.width = "Auto"

$grd.RowDefinitions.add($row1)
$grd.RowDefinitions.add($row2)
$grd.ColumnDefinitions.add($col1)
$grd.ColumnDefinitions.add($col2)

   $NewButton = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
   $NewButton.Content = "Label " + $counter 
   $NewButton.Name = "FirstLabel"
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($NewButton,0)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($NewButton,1)

  $grd.AddChild($NewButton)

   $NewButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
   $newButton2.Name = "SecondLabel"
   $NewButton2.Content = "Label " + ($counter + 2 )
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($NewButton2,1)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($NewButton2,0)

   $newButton2.HorizontalAlignment = 'Right'


$grd.AddChild($NewButton2)

return $grd
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set properties like this, use the static method on the "parent" class:

```
[System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($label,0)
[System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($label,1)
```

Comment: That was it.  the $label is actually part of a function that is called whenever i needed a new grid and label created.  substituting your suggestions to what i had worked nicely and now i can place the new 'sub-grid' and labels wherever i need them.  -Thanks!